# PHP Convert nested associative array to Json object for cURL

Tags: php, json, curl

In an API Integration... I need to pass json data to the CURL.
Here is how the API Specs look like

```
curl -X POST \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer {token}" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '
      {
          "from": "12345",
          "to": [
              "123456789",
          ],
          "body": "Hi there! How are you?"
      }' \
  "https://api.service.com/xms/v1/batches"
```

This is my array

```
 private $post_data = array('from' => '91875222222',
    'to' => array('918757022222'),
    'body' => 'I am test robot.');
```

Inside function callAPI()... Converting it to json format to pass data to url

```
$test = json_encode(array($this->post_data), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $test);
```

I am trying this way...however ... when I try to print $test data it outputs

> {\"from\":\"918757095588\",\"to\":[\"918757095588\"],\"body\":\"I am
>   intelligent test robot.\"}"}

with no success. Not sure what is missing. I have set the header authorization as:

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer 2cfe3a1d8899019db3512222a9fecb'
    );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Comment: FYI, `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` is unnecessary here as associative arrays always encode to an object.

Comment: You shouldn't need to place the post_data within another array in your json_encode.